# How do I improve this title?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, title

Recently, I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/angularjs-in-url-instead-of-migrating-to-angularjs-1-6).

It is a question about a new feature of AngularJS and many people are asking questions about (not only on Stack Overflow). I found it useful, so I think it would be interesting that this issue could be more visible on Stack Overflow and search engines.

The problem is this question is bad referenced, because it deals with special characters in the URL. Characters such as `#`, `/` or `!` are often ignored in Google searches, making this question impossible to find.

**How can we improve the title of this question to be clearer, easier to find?**

---

The original title was *"AngularJS #!/ in url instead of #/ (Migrating to AngularJS 1.6)"*.

The title has been changed by someone recently, but the question is still opened.

Comment: Symbols are always hard; there is no magic solution. Browsing the answers, it looks like "AngularJS 1.6" and "hash prefix" are the important keywords. I'm not sure if that will help searchability, though. Will someone asking this question know that this is called a "hash prefix"?

Comment: @CodyGray: Interesting comment. I don't think everybody call `#/` a *hash-prefix* because it only has a name in docs, but when I read this word, in found it clear. Maybe **#!/ hash-prefix in URL instead of #/ (migrating to AngularJS 1.6)** could help browsing?

Answer (score -1):

For titles about symbols, I've seen that those that include the name of the symbol along the symbol itself tend to be search friendly enough. I've done exactly that.

Comment: I understand your logic, but I'm still not sure that people will research *"hash bang prefix"*. I wished we do not rename the question now, but to be discussed

Comment: @Mistalis https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+equal+greater+than and more like that are popular queries.